# bundle install error with linux mageia 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am getting the following error despite using all methods stated in this forum. I am running mageia 2 linux

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    checking for sqlite3.h... yes
    checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
    sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
    or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
    location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 3):

On a 64 bit Mageia System, you have to use

```
urpmi lib64sqlite3-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

The quesiton has limited information on your environment, such as ruby version and what your initial command was. Because of that this answer may be incomplete.

The error states:

`checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no     sqlite3 is missing.`

This is the reason that the sqlite3 gem is not installing. Make cannot find the sqlite3 header files. I'm not familiar with the Mageia Linxux distribution, but it seems to be based on Mandriva. I believe if you follow the instructions in the error message and run:

`yum install sqlite-devel`

sqlite-devel will install and you will be able to execute the original `gem install sqlite3` or `bundle` command.

Comment: thanks so much. it worked. but for mageia i used (urpmi sqlite-devel instead of yum install) ok, this will be for others with similar distributions.